# Simple CA web interface for SSL certificates tracking/request/generation

Tags: centos, certificate, certificate-authority

I am using the nice XCA packge on my WS to generate and track the keys and CSRs we submit to various CAs, track the certificates we get back from then and to manage the full lifecycle of other self-signed certificates we generate for internal use.

Now I need to share this task with other coworkers, but XCA does not fit the bill, essentially because we need something that will run on a Centos5 machine and have a web interface.

I have been on the openCA site, but the rpms cater mostly to fedora 12 and up. I could try and build fresh RPMs, but that often proves a fruitless, frustrating activity.

Does anybody know of a package that would fulfill my requisites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally use [EJBCA](http://www.ejbca.org/). It works quite well, you can delegate privileges to other people (set what kind of certificates they can create), can publish certificates in LDAP, works as OCSP server.

The only grievance is that it is quite resource heavy, a 1GB RAM is a reasonable minimum, with 768MB the system is swapping.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look it up, but the "EJB" part probably means that it's not suitable exactly for the reason you mention - the CA related activity is  peripheral enough to not warrant the resources/maintenance hurdle of an EJB site.

Comment: Setting it up is definitely non trivial, but after that, it's basically maintenance free.